# Replacing a fragment on button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

*I already owe a lot of credit to a user of SO for getting me this far, but after 6+ hours of developer page reading I still cannot get this to work on an Android emulator.*

I am simply trying to swap one fragment for another. What happens when the button is clicked is the initial frag animates quickly, but stays put. It only animates once and subsequent button presses do not produce subsequent animations. I don't know if that's because for some reason the onCreate code is somehow running again quickly replacing the initial frag over the "click frag" or if the issue is in the `replaceFrag` method itself or if something is executing incorrectly. *If anyone sees the issue and could point to where it is (without a full detailed explanation), I'd be very appreciative. When I get it to work I will award that person the green check and post the solution as well.*

Here is the Main_Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Add the fragment to'fragment_container' 
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            Menu_Fragment fragment = new Menu_Fragment();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "INITIAL_FRAG");
            ft.commit();
        }

        public void replaceFrag(View v) {

            Fragment fragment = new Click_Fragment();   //Creates a new Click_Fragment when button selected
            Fragment savedFragment = null;             // creates an instance of savedFragment
            if (fragment != null) { //check to see if fragment was instantiated, always true

                savedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FB");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                if (savedFragment != null) {//searches to see if the Click_Fragment has already been created once
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, savedFragment, "FB");
                } else {
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "FB");
                }

                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

The button, which has its XML housed in the menu_fragment layout, has the attribute:
`android:onClick="replaceFrag"`

EDIT: This error appears in the SDK log when button is pressed:
`mycompany.fragment_test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab70a680, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain why you have both of these lines in `replaceFrag()`:

```
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
```

I recommend stepping through by either debugging or using log statements to see what's happening. You might even print off the backstack at the of `replaceFrag()`. Additionally, I would not set `replaceFrag()` in XML.

Comment: If I remember correctly, addToBackStack alows the user to get to the previous fragment by pressing the back button on the android device. The setTransition() animates the replacement of the fragment.

Comment: Where would you set replaceFrag? as an onClickListener?